# Naming and meaning of exponential power functions

Tags: probability-distributions, exponential-function

I apologize if something like this has already been asked, but I don't have any ideas on search terms for this family of functions.

I'd like to know two things:

1) Is there a name for the family of functions of the form

$$f(t)= \exp{(-kt^n)}$$

Specifically, for $n=1$, it's just an exponential decay, and for $n=2$, it's a Gaussian (or Normal) distribution. What about situations where n is fractional (*i.e.* ${3}/{2}$)?

2) Is there any physical meaning for these types of functions? I realize this portion might belong on the Physics.SX site, so if no one has ideas, I can transfer part 2 over there. To elaborate on what I mean by "physical meaning", I work with NMR signals, and an exponential decay $(n=1)$ indicates a system with homogeneous broadening of lifetimes, and a Gaussian decay indicates inhomogenous broadening of lifetimes.

Comment: I believe [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/195384/is-there-a-name-for-this-family-of-probability-distributions) answers part 1 of my question, but I'm still left with part 2… perhaps I should migrate over to Phys.SX…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is (for my specific case) a compressed exponential function, and the general function family is the [generalized normal distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_normal_distribution). For a physically relevant application of the compressed exponential, see the cross-posting [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/99472/meaning-of-generalized-normal-distribution). Essentially, it comes from the observed relaxation curve being comprised of a distribution of Gaussian decay curves.